# Show keyboard when Textfield inside Alert in WkWebView is tapped

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, wkwebview, becomefirstresponder

There is a game that i load in the WKWebView and this Alert and textField appear after the game is finished. I want to display keyboard when user taps on the textField. But the problem is **there is no code to display this alert and textfield**, otherwise i would have managed the textField to becomeFirstResponder().

Desperately need some help. I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Trying to help but you say the alert and textfield displays and also that there is no code to display the alert and textfield so how? Surely you have code somewhere to display it? Can you show it / the code? If it is plain HTML then the keyboard should show automatically and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: yes the alert code does not exist. it's html, textfield is focused but still no keyboard. This alert has nothing to do with my code. I didnot dispaly it. it automatically appears once the game is finished.

Comment: Sounds like a WK quirk ... what happens if you add ```autofocus``` to it e.g. ```<input type="text" autofocus />```

Comment: where am i supposed to enter this line? <input type="text" autofocus />

Comment: In the HTML!? Where you define the textfield ...

Comment: If you can not access or edit the HTML how can you change its behaviour? Where does this come from if you don't display it?

Comment: okay let me explain. It's a game. I simply pushed it to WkWebView as i know the url. The game loads in the WkWebView. User spends a few good minutes playing it and once the game is finished, this alert popups. This textfield and alert has nothing to do with my code that's the whole problem. If i had presented this alert, i would have somehow figured it out, but i didn't present it. it has nothing to do with my code. :|

Please don't ask me why would i push it to WKWebView. its a client based project so i had to do what i was told to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222531/discussion-between-naveedulhassan5-and-skaak).

Comment: Please edit your question with essential new info and code, don't put that in the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: is the cursor in the TextField blinking and can you touch or click the textfield? It may be just a displayed image.

Comment: Yes, the cursor was blinking.The textField was focused. Anyways i found the solution. Thankyou everyone. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i have found the solution. I had a textField in custom Alert/Popup in WkwebView and i wanted the textField to `becomeFirstResponder()` so i could take user input.

// So i Implemented WKUIDelegate..

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface MyController : UIViewController<WKUIDelegate>
```

Assigned the Delegate..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     _webkitView.UIDelegate = self;
}
```

//implemented delegate function.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt:(NSString *)prompt defaultText:(NSString *)defaultText initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *result))completionHandler
{
    
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"BlockChaid Id, Email or Username"
                                                                   message:prompt
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = prompt;
        textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
        textField.text = defaultText;
    }];
    
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        completionHandler(nil);
    }]];
    
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        completionHandler([alert.textFields.firstObject text]);
    }]];
    
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After successful build, this was the output.

1. I tapped the textField, and javaScript Alert appeared.

[image]

1. This right here is what i wanted to achieve.

[image]

Maybe i was not good enough to explain my question, but this is what i was asking for. Thank you :)